# How to convert existing fiscal year to other pandas datetime format?

Tags: pandas, datetime, strftime

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
| FiscalYearMonthName | FiscalWeek |
|---------------------|------------|
| FY19-Jul | FY19-W1 (Jun 30 - Jul 06) |
| FY19-Jul | FY19-W1 (Jul 07 - Jul 13) |
```

My desired outcome is to add a column that looks like the following:

```
07/06/2018
07/13/2018
```

I think this might involve using `pd.datetime(df['FiscalWeek'], format = %f)`. I'm guessing this is a one-liner in pandas - how can I modify this line of code to convert the FiscalWeek to my desired outcome?

Comment: how is your fiscal year defined?

Comment: July-June @anky

Comment: @Nate, so your end goal to convert `FY19-W1 (Jun 30 - Jul 06) ` to  `07/06/2018`  ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @KarnKumar